# webpack 4 scss loader doesn't work - why?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My configuration is:

```
{
  test: '/\.(css|scss)$/',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'
  ]
}
```

but I get the following error:

> ERROR in ./src/components/button/button.scss 1:10
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   > $font-size: 20px;

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to use a regex for `test`, but you're actually using a string. Remove the `'`s around the regex pattern and it should work:

```
{
    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
    ...
}
```